# PHP Laravel 5.5 functions

Tags: php, laravel

[Products table structure](https://prnt.sc/i8b567)

My API should return values (not ids) and that is what i need. In PHP i just did queries to search tables for values, i guess in laravel way for that is close but i am new in this framework and need little help ;]

I was searching and construct something like this :

```
$products = Products::all();
        foreach ($products as $key => $product) {
            $product->id_Model = DB::table('models')->select('model')->where('id', '=', $product->id_Model)->get();
        }
```

"models" table contains names
"products" table contains ids of "models" -> products.id_Models = models.id
I i said above my API result should be names instead of ids so i need to search for name of every product before i put it into json.

Comment: what  is a slave tables?

Comment: `$product->id_Model` is used for set some value to single model. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: you have not setup relations or you have no idea how models work in laravel. This could be simplified so much more with proper relations and model setup. Try reading https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#defining-models for some help

Answer (score 0):

Ok i get to point i wanted to be result of work

API :

```
https://prnt.sc/i8cy9w
```

DB :

```
https://prnt.sc/i8cytv
```

Values ale "fake" ones from Seeders, now i only need to fix doubles

/edit
Fixed now it works well :

```
https://prnt.sc/i8d4u5
```

example line: `$product->id_Colors = DB::table('colors')->select('color')->where('id', '=', $product->id_Colors)->value('color');`